# Customizing marker size of pyplot.scatter in a general way

Tags: python, matplotlib

[This site](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html) has information on customizing Matplotlib.  I am looking for a way to customize the marker size for the markers plotted using `pyplot.scatter()`.  I know that I can use the `s` parameter directly in `pyplot.scatter()` but I would like a way to define the marker size more generally that in each individual call to `pyplot.scatter()`.  However, in the site I linked above I am unable to find a way to do so.

Comment: This is way too vague. What is more general than being able to pass an array for each point?

Comment: Using the matplotlibrc configuration files, as discussed on the site I linked.

Comment: I still don't understand. Provide examples of what you'd like to see.

Comment: By "general" do you actually mean "universal"?

Comment: I mean, for a specific Python script I write, I would like a one line command that changes the default value of this particular parameter (the `s` parameter of `pyplot.scatter()`) to be whatever I tell it to be.

Comment: why not just use `plt.plot` and set the default `markersize` in your matplotlibrc file the usual way?

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the scatter function:

```
def new_scatter(x, y):
    area = some_func(x, y)
    plt.scatter(x, y, s=area)
```

And then just call `new_scatter` from then on. If you need to, you can even overwrite the old scatter:

```
old_scatter = plt.scatter
plt.scatter = new_scatter
```

Comment: I think overwriting `plt.scatter` is a bad idea. The next person who comes behind you is going to be very confused.